# Compare text box value with drop down list values

Tags: infopath

I need to compare the value in a text box to values in a separate drop-down list box. for instance if the value in the text is *username* and this value does not exist in the drop-down, then disable the another field.

The problem at the moment is that the comparison is only working for the first drop-down value.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248976/check-if-value-is-in-select-list-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Using this technique it works. I have tested it both with a drop-down using a sharepoint list or a drop-down using a sql connection.

Basically add a rule to the text box field. Make the condition textboxfield = username  in SP list.  When InfoPath does the check it actually checks each value in the repeating nodes and if any or more match it will return TRUE, if not, it matches FALSE.

http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/9172/32453.aspx

Comment: Please add details from the link to your post. If the link breaks your answer will be of no help to future readers as it is now